# Any punishment for the own launch?

Tags: launch

Rewatching the [Astronaut Farmer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469263/?ref_=nv_sr_4?ref_=nv_sr_4) movie got me thinking: if I own a land and am capable/rich enough to build a rocket to launch from this land - will I be punished somehow for doing it? (presuming I'm able to successfully return of course)

Let the location be U.S. (or Europe if that matters somehow)

Comment: This will come down to what own really means. In the absolute sense only goverments fullt own land.

Comment: Jeff Bezos is a rich guy who launches rockets from his land in West Texas.  So it demonstrably can be done.

Comment: I'm sure there's a permitting process involving multiple federal agencies (yay bureaucracy!) but as @OrganicMarble says it can and has been done.  If you mean just building a large rocket (the movie rocket is orbit-capable) and launching it without telling/asking anyone, then yeah you're probably going to have to answer some questions at the very least.

Comment: @lijat, One could debate the meaning of the word, "own" (as in, whether or not governments truly "own" land). Governments do, however, exercise _[sovereignty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereignty)_ over it.

Comment: @ben, If there ever was a bureaucracy to cheer for, the U.S. FAA probably comes as close as any other. They work hard to protect people from harming each other, they are indifferent about helping corporations to increase their profits (or at least, that's how it was last time I paid them any attention), and they absolutely _will_ allow you to kill yourself so long as you don't put the public at risk at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the FAA did a very poor job of riding herd on Virgin Galactic, they were all about go-fever at the expense of safety.  If you read the accident report the FAA comes off very, very badly. http://www.parabolicarc.com/2018/02/27/george-nield-retire-faa/

Comment: OK, well, full disclosure: My impression was formed sometime back in the 1980s when I tried for a private pilot's license. I guess that attitudes and policies in government may have changed _somewhat_ since those days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  It is illegal in the US to launch a rocket of that magnitude without a license.  It is actually a huge burden to get such clearance (I wonder why...).  The entire process is outlined [here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/licenses_permits/).  Basically, you need to prove a few things, like:

1. Any failures won't endanger anyone
2. You are doing this for purely civilian reasons

The process begins with notifying the FAA that you intend to do this, and then a relatively lengthy process takes place in which your site and vehicle are studied against many regulations.

Comment: Yes, so my idea was that "a person just did it" - without much following the rules. Am I assuming that if one just blindly does it - then he/she is a subject to some penalties according to the regulations you've mentioned?

Comment: As it is illegal to launch rockets in your back yard and the fact that even an "unarmed" rocket is still a huge bomb, you will get legal punishment for it.

Comment: @AlmaDo it's similar to flying a passenger jet without following the rules. Even if you built a big enough runway on your ranch, and you bought a 747 or something, you can't just take off and fly.  There are so many reasons why, but one of the bigger ones is that airspace is protected.  Planes aren't flying randomly, they are following pre-set flight paths to prevent midair collisions and the like.  A rocket suddenly flying into one of those paths would be a huge danger, and that's just the beginning.  So yes, you can't "just do it" :-P

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky well for airplanes it's simple to understand for me: I can (potentially) trespass into the air space of other countries or protected military space. But with the rocket I don't really do it. I just fly away to the space and that's it, no real trespassing in terms of air space

Comment: Well it's not just the airspace of another country.  You can't fly into an airport without following the proper flight path even in your own country.  I suppose if you were far enough away from a population center then airspace wouldn't be the major concern, but that's not an endorsement to try to fly an orbital rocket without approval :-P In fact, many high power rocketry hobbyists are required to file for a license even though they don't go anywhere close to orbital.  It's easier to get a hobby high power license than an orbital one...

Comment: If you can launch to orbit, you (or perhaps some bad guys who steal your rocket) can launch on a ballistic trajectory to hit any city you want, in your own country or another. Extra fuel and oxidizer will make a pretty effective explosive payload as well. Reasonably enough governments have concerns in this situation, both for the loss of life and because they don't like individual citizens risking starting a nuclear war.

Comment: I think the answer honestly boils down to, "exactly **how** rich are you?"

Comment: @AlmaDo Something you apparently don't realize about going to space--while a rocket starts out lifting straight up it soon tips over, most of the burn is nearly horizontal.  That's why for maximum payload Falcon 9 stages are recovered well out to sea--because they were heading that way.  Nobody owns enough land for the whole flight path to be over their property.  If you want to survive the flight that burn takes place over several hundred miles.